# How to use a custom Comparer to sort an Array in a different lexical order?

Tags: c#, sorting, compare

So, I'm pretty new to C# and I'm trying to order an Array using a custom Comparer.

I created a class:

```
class MySorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var chars = "jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht";
        if (chars.IndexOf((char)x) < chars.IndexOf((char)y))
            return -1;
        return chars.IndexOf((char)x) > chars.IndexOf((char)y) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

And I have a Array full of words. 
How exacly I can use this Compare to sort?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that what you need is this. Declare a method for sorting as you already did.

```
public static int CompareStrings(string s1, string s2)
{
    // TODO: your code here
}
```

... and specify what function you need to use.

```
string[] myStrings = { ... };
Array.Sort(myStrings, CompareStrings);
```

If you use generic classes, you can achieve this as well doing as it follows:

```
List<string> myStrings = ...;
myStrings.Sort(CompareStrings);
```

Comment: Ok, now I can use my method, but I'm getting an InvalidCastException here: `if (chars.IndexOf((char)x) < chars.IndexOf((char)y))` any idea why?

Comment: x is either an `object` or a `string` so you need to cast it as a char, not with `(char)x` but `Convert.ToChar(x)`

Comment: I tried it before, but then I got a 'System.FormatException'. I think that is happening because I have the whole string there. e.g "gmxz". Do I need to substring my string and get just the first char before comparing?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can compare strings as well, but use the `Equals()` method. Well, if you have a string, you can't convert it into a char, you need to either pas char by char, or pass the entire string and compare strings, not chars.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question **for people wishing to use Linq** the solution would be:

```
IEnumerable<string> words = new [] {"foo", "bar"};
words = words.OrderBy(x => x, new MySorter());
```

Note therefore that you should be using the generic interface for your comparer:

```
class MySorter : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {

    }
}
```

You can then use Linq to sort even objects:

```
IEnumerable<Person>  people = new []
{
    new Person
    {
        Name = "Matthew"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Name = "Mark"
    }
};
people = people.OrderBy(x => x.Name, new MySorter());
```

**An important note relating to some of the issues you highlighted under Simply Me's answer:**

*Using the generic interface is always preferable when the types being compared are known*, as amongst other things this would have alerted you at compile time rather than run time (when you got an `InvalidCastException`) that if you are sorting an array of *words*, assuming a word is a `string`, the `IComparer` you are implementing is not fit for purpose as it is comparing two `char` types.

(From what I am inferring by looking at your code, I think what you need to do is implement `IComparer<string>` and in the `Compare` method iterate through each `char` of both strings until they differ, and then use your `char` comparison logic - but, you should also consider how you handle uppercase and lowercase, what you do when one or both characters are not in your list and if one `string` in its entirety matches the first part of the other `string`, such as *match* and *matches*.)

Answer (score 0):

An inline solution with an anonymous function. It will sort your strings in lexicographical order.

```
Array.Sort(arr, (a, b) => string.CompareOrdinal(a, b));
```

It will turn

```
var arr = new[] { "orange", "banana", "apple", "watermelon", "tomato" };
```

into

```
string[5] { "apple", "banana", "orange", "tomato", "watermelon" }
```